# Placing border-image bottom to a div

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the floated elements to which I want to give some background image at the end of a box as this:

```
+--------------------+    +-------------------+     +---------------------+
|                    |    |                   |     |                     |
|                    |    |                   |     |                     |
+--------------------+    +-------------------+     +---------------------+
  ================           ==============            =================
```

But this goes likely to this:

```
===========================================================================
+--------------------+    +-------------------+     +---------------------+
|                    |    |                   |     |                     |
|                    |    |                   |     |                     |
+--------------------+    +-------------------+     +---------------------+
===========================================================================
```

I have used the border property instead of an image here. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p7mBk/)**

Comment: Floated elements do not span up the height of their parent element – except under conditions like f.e. that parent element is floated itself, or has `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Sorry your html and css are highly improper

Comment: @Dolours Short demo http://jsfiddle.net/p7mBk/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to what you want to achieve. I just modified your [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML). Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/p7mBk/5/

#### CSS

```
.cf:before, .cf:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    zoom: 1;
}
.mainb {
    width: 1000px;
}
.fleft {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
.fright {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
.midcol {
    margin: 0 310px;
}
.cmnbrd {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.spacer {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 0 12px;
}
```

And the HTML is

```
<div class="mainb cf">
    <div class="fleft">
        <div class="cmnbrd">
            <h3>Latuis Congue Estaer</h3>
            <img src="" alt="" />
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue blandit diam sed ullamcorper. Morbi vitae metus a purus rhoncus egestas ac sit amet velit. Sed ac eros eu tellus adipiscing consectetur a ut mi. Nunc imperdiet pretium metus ac auctor. </p>
            <p class="alt"><a href="#">More</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fright">
        <div class="cmnbrd">
            <h3>Latuis Congue Estaer</h3>
            <img src="" />
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue blandit diam sed ullamcorper. Morbi vitae metus a purus rhoncus egestas ac sit amet velit. Sed ac eros eu tellus adipiscing consectetur a ut mi. Nunc imperdiet pretium metus ac auctor. </p>
            <p class="alt"><a href="#">More</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="midcol">
        <div class="cmnbrd">
            <h3>Latuis Congue Estaer</h3>
            <img src="" />
            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue blandit diam sed ullamcorper. Morbi vitae metus a purus rhoncus egestas ac sit amet velit. Sed ac eros eu tellus adipiscing consectetur a ut mi. Nunc imperdiet pretium metus ac auctor. </p>
            <p class="alt"><a href="#">More</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh! Yeah! I should have wrapped in one div to fleft and spacer and so on. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `clear` to your spacer:

```
.spacer {clear: both;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p7mBk/7/

Comment: clear: both is not necessary. You have placed spacer html another way i.e. I was wrong with my html. Thanks. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and floated all the elements. Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/p7mBk/3/

#### CSS

```
.cf:before, .cf:after{display: table; content: " ";}
.cf:after{clear: both;}
.cf{zoom: 1;}

.mainb{width: 1000px;}
.fleft{float: left; width: 300px;}
.fright{float: left; width: 300px;}
.midcol{float: left;width:310px;}
.fleft, .fright, .midcol{border: 1px solid red;}
.spacer{border: 1px solid gray; border-top: 0; background: blue; height: 2px; margin: 0 12px;}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="mainb cf">
    <div class="fleft">
        <h3>Latuis Congue Estaer</h3>
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue blandit diam sed ullamcorper. Morbi vitae metus a purus rhoncus egestas ac sit amet velit. Sed ac eros eu tellus adipiscing consectetur a ut mi. Nunc imperdiet pretium metus ac auctor. </p>
        <p class="alt"><a href="#">More</a></p>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fright">
        <h3>Latuis Congue Estaer</h3>
        <img src="" />
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue blandit diam sed ullamcorper. Morbi vitae metus a purus rhoncus egestas ac sit amet velit. Sed ac eros eu tellus adipiscing consectetur a ut mi. Nunc imperdiet pretium metus ac auctor. </p>
        <p class="alt"><a href="#">More</a></p>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="midcol">
        <h3>Latuis Congue Estaer</h3>
        <img src="" />
        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur congue blandit diam sed ullamcorper. Morbi vitae metus a purus rhoncus egestas ac sit amet velit. Sed ac eros eu tellus adipiscing consectetur a ut mi. Nunc imperdiet pretium metus ac auctor. </p>
        <p class="alt"><a href="#">More</a></p>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It may be what you want.

Comment: Sorry! spacer border should be outside

Answer (score 0):

As everyone here suggested while I wrote this, you have to put the spacer inside the `div`. Otherwise, it doesn't know where it belongs and which width to use. If you want to have the red borders outside the spacer, simply add another div for the content:

```
<column>
    <border>
        <text/>
    </border>
    <spacer/>
</column>
```